# Redirect results from ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to a log file

Tags: delphi

I want to add memory leak detection to our automated Unit tests. ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown will detect any memory leaks. The big problem is that it prints the results to a modal dialog box, which has to be closed manually by the user. This does not work in an automated Unit test running on a build server.

Is there any way to redirect the output from ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to somewhere else? For example, print the information to a file?

The doco says:

> the Memory Manager will scan the
>   memory pool when it shuts down and
>   report all unregistered memory leaks
>   *in a message dialog*.

I am using Delphi 2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the full version of [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) from sourceforge. You can configure it to write to a logfile in FastMM4Options.inc; just check the readme and FAQ files in the download for details. Specifically, look for information regarding `FullDebugMode` and `LogErrorsToFile`, and the third or fourth question in the FAQ readme.

Comment: There are also some variable to control it programmatically, but to get a useful log some options may need to be set in the .inc file neverthless.

Comment: @lsandon, that's why I specifically said to read the FAQ and readme files as well as the .inc file. What did I miss?

Comment: So doesn't Delphi come with FastMM? Do I have to download it again to use this option?

Comment: @awmross: You need to download it (and add it correctly as the first unit in your *project* source - use 'Project->View Source' from the IDE main menu) in order to use FullDebugMode. It's free, open source. The info in the readme and other text files will make it fairly clear, as will the .inc file comments.