# How could I save the memory leak report to text file with default Delphi installation?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect results from ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399395/redirect-results-from-reportmemoryleaksonshutdown-to-a-log-file)

I've been using ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to show memory leaks in my code, but now I would like to know if is it possibe to redirect that report to string or text with default delphi installation, in order to be part of the debug log my app builds

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399395/redirect-results-from-reportmemoryleaksonshutdown-to-a-log-file

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Looks like it's a duplicate :P I've been looking around but did not find it. I will check this LURD link. Thanks a lot